# How can I implements geofirestore in an app with React Native Cli?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am trying to use `geofirestore` to get from the documents of a collection those that are a certain distance from the user's location in a `react native Cli` application, when trying to implement geofirestore I get the following TypeError:

> error: _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[9 ], "(...)estore").GeoFirestore.collection is not a function (it is undefined), could you help me solve this problem please

note: the implementation of firestore is correct since I have other methods where documents from firestore collections are obtained correctly, I only get the error with the implementation of geofirestore

These are the versions that are installed in the project

```json
"firebase": "^9.23.0",
"geofirestore": "^5.2.0",
```

**this is my firebase configuration file**

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

import { GeoFirestore } from 'geofirestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const authentication = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

const geofirestore = new GeoFirestore(db);

export { app, authentication, db,  geofirestore };
```

**and this is my file where I implement geofirestore**

```js
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import GetLocation from 'react-native-get-location'
import { collection, onSnapshot, orderBy, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../utils/keys"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

import { GeoFirestore } from 'geofirestore';

const obtenerRegistrosCercanos = async () => {
   
    const eventosCollection = GeoFirestore.collection(db,'eventos');
    
    const center = new firestore.GeoPoint(19.325471, -99.656188);

    const radius = 10;

    const query = eventosCollection.near({
        center,
        radius,
      });

      query.get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          console.log(data);
        });
      });     
  };
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question about GeoFirestore, but with the new ability to have range conditions on multiple fields you might not need that library anymore. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/multiple-range-fields